# error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript

```js
var calc = {
  '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
  '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
  '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
  '/': function (x, y) { return x / y }
};
var firstNum = prompt("first number");
var secondNum = prompt("second number");
var opr = prompt("+, -, * or /?");
var ans = calc['+'](1,2);
console.log("the answer is " + ans "!");
```

this is my code, it gives me an error, why?

can someone help me?

Comment: share error msg

Comment: also try replacing `"the answer is " + ans + "!";`

Comment: The last line is not a statement nor a valid expression. What is it supposed to do? Store the text in a variable or log it to the console?

Comment: You're missing a `+` in the last line... And even if you add it, your last line will be useless (creates a string and discards it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you forgot a `+` in

```
"the answer is " + ans "!";
```

and you need `console.log(ans)` or `alert(ans);` in order to see the result:

```js
var calc = {
        '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
        '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
        '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
        '/': function (x, y) { return x / y }
    };
    var firstNum = prompt("first number");
    var secondNum = prompt("second number");
    var opr = prompt("+, -, * or /?");
    var ans = calc[opr](firstNum,secondNum);
    console.log("the answer is " + ans +"!");
    alert("the answer is " + ans +"!");
```

Comment: yeah and i also forgot to do "number()"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can not put your string like this in a JS code.

Another bug i found is that the prompt is a returning a string type, so you need to convert them to a number, otherwise your function that make the addition, threat it as a string and concatenate the numbers:

```
var calc = {
    '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
    '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
    '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
    '/': function (x, y) { return x / y }
};
var firstNum = prompt("first number");
var secondNum = prompt("second number");

var opr = prompt("+, -, * or /?");
var ans = calc[opr](Number(firstNum),Number(secondNum)); // prompt is a string
console.log(`The answer is ${ans}`)
```

Comment: Actually, you **can** put a string like that in JS code (if you don't forget the `+`, of course), it just won't do anything. Otherwise you're correct...

Comment: Yeah, i mean, you can still do it, but you won't be able see the content you want to see, that's what i mean :D

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the error like this.

```js
var calc = {
    '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
    '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
    '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
    '/': function (x, y) { return x / y }
};
var firstNum = prompt("first number");
var secondNum = prompt("second number");
var opr = prompt("+, -, * or /?");
var ans = calc[opr](firstNum,secondNum);
alert(`The Answer is ${ans}`);
```

> But here the values that you are taking from prompt are strings.
>   ie; 1 + 2 would be 12

You should covert the string to Number like this

```js
var calc = {
    '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
    '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
    '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
    '/': function (x, y) { return x / y }
};
var firstNum = prompt("first number");
var secondNum = prompt("second number");
var opr = prompt("+, -, * or /?");
var ans = calc[opr](Number(firstNum),Number(secondNum));
alert(`The answer is ${ans}`)
// "the answer is " + ans "!";
```